# How to execute a GDB command from a string variable?

Tags: scripting, debugging, gdb

Say the debugged process has a string variable as follows:

```
char* cmd_str = "set confirm on";
```

How to execute the command from `cmd_str` in GDB?

```
(gdb) $cmd = cmd_str
(gdb) ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use gdb's `eval` command, which runs `printf` on its arguments and then evaluates the result as a command.

```
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdlib.h>
2   main()
3   {
4       char *a = "set confirm off";
5   
6       pause();
7   }
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400540: file cmdtest.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./cmdtest 
Breakpoint 1, main () at cmd.c:6
6       pause();

(gdb) show confirm
Whether to confirm potentially dangerous operations is on.
(gdb) printf "%s", a
set confirm off(gdb) 
(gdb) eval "%s", a
(gdb) show confirm
Whether to confirm potentially dangerous operations is off.
```